# I need to combine a sum in SQL

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I would like to combine the total sum of lightcount and TotalLightCount 
Say for example if lightcount = 100 and TotalLightCount = 300 the final sum would be 400. This is the code that I have so far but they I'm getting two sums instead of a combined amount.

```
<%  
Set rstest = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sql = "SELECT SUM(count) AS TotalCount, SELECT SUM(lightcount) AS TotalLightCount FROM Records;" 
rstest.Open sql, db
%>
```

Comment: your question is  not clear what exactly you need

Comment: Please, present Records table example, and the output that would be more than two rows, so we could at least guess what you mean.

Comment: I would like to combine the amounts of Columns TotalCount and TotalightCount into one amount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT SUM(count) + SUM(lightcount) AS GrandTotal 
  FROM Records;
```

or

```
SELECT SUM(count) AS TotalCount, 
       SUM(lightcount) AS TotalLightCount,
       SUM(count) + SUM(lightcount) AS GrandTotal 
  FROM Records;
```

if you need all three columns in the resultset

Comment: Actaully that was a great answer. Thanks

Comment: @Jimmy Great! You're very welcome :) If you feel like the answer was helpful please, consider to **[accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you,

```
SELECT column1, column2, (column1+column2) AS SumColumn FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%  
Set rstest = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sql = "SELECT SUM(count) + SELECT SUM(lightcount) AS TotalLightCount FROM Records;" 
rstest.Open sql, db
%>
```